Why does complex convolution not involve conjugating the other function while correlation does?
The convolution of two functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is defined as
$$
\begin{equation}
(f * g)(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u) g(t - u) du.
\end{equation}
$$
while the cross-correlation of $f$ and $g$ is defined as
$$
\begin{equation}
(f \star g)(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{f(u)} g(u + t) du
\end{equation}
$$
and the inner product of $f$ and $g$ is defined as
$$
\begin{equation}
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{f(u)} g(u) du.
\end{equation}
$$
The connection between the cross-correlation and the inner product is clear as the cross-correlation is basically the inner product of $f$ and a shifted version of $g$. However, the connection between the convolution and the inner product / cross-correlation is not clear to me.
I have a clear understanding of how multiplying $\overline{x} \in \mathbb{C}$ by $y \in \mathbb{C}$ can be interpreted visually. $\operatorname{Re}(\overline{x} y)$ tells "how parallel $x$ and $y$ are" (negative value indicating "anti-parallelness") while $\operatorname{Im}(\overline{x} y)$ tells "how perpendicular to the left of $x$ is $y$" (negative value indicating "right-perpendicularness"), both being scaled by the magnitudes of $x$ and $y$. The real and imaginary components of the inner product can then be interpreted respectively as sort of like an average "parallelness" and "left-perpendicularness" of $f$ and $g$ which to me is a quite natural given the inner product's interpretation as a measure of similarity.
But why doesn't the convolution have one of the function complex conjugated in the integral?
The visual interpretation of $xy$ is also clear to me. We rotate $y$ by $\operatorname{Arg}(x)$ and then multiply by $|x|$. Another way to think about what the product $xy$ means, is that the real part of $xy$ tells "how much more of a mirror image $x$ and $y$ are wrt. the real axis than wrt. the imaginary axis" while the imaginary part tells "how much more of a mirror image $x$ and $y$ are wrt. to the line $\operatorname{Im}(z) = \operatorname{Re}(z)$ than wrt. the line $\operatorname{Im}(z) = -\operatorname{Re}(z)$".
Why do we want to measure this in the convolution instead of the usual measure of similarity i.e. "parallelness" and "left-perpendicularness" as in the inner product and cross-correlation? Is there some relation between the convolution and the cross-correlation that gives a natural reason for why the convolution is defined in this way? I'm guessing that the convolution is used for a different purpose: in a way, modifying the function $f$ by $g$ the same fashion as with the real version of sliding window average but averaging in a "complex way", and not used for measuring similarity as with the inner product and cross-correlation.

Convolution is supposed to be commutative and associative and adding the complex conjugation in would mess that up. It also is supposed to be Fourier dual to pointwise multiplication and, again, adding the complex conjugation in would mess that up. The role of the complex conjugation in the inner product and cross-correlation (which is the inner product with one of the functions translated) is to ensure positive-definiteness.
